# Update Apache Beam Jave RunTime for Dataflow runner from Java8 to Java11

Tags: google-cloud-functions, pipeline, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

We have compose function written in node.js and DAG written in python and the data flow job is in Java. All the dependencies including the dataflow job is compiled in java11 and when I try to run the dataflow job, getting
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: apache_beam_2/EdnCoder has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdwYq.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqaVG.png)

I am not sure how to set the runtime to java11.
As apache/beam_java11_sdk is one of the default images, looking to set that as runtime version.
sdkContainerImage part of pipeline option is one way but I dont have any customization need here, so checking if there is any straight forward way of changing the java runtime version.

Comment: It is probably the Java version that you are using to start/stage the pipeline. Please check with `java -version` on the same context as it is very likely Java 8 (version 52.0), and try to bump it to Java 11 (version 55.0).

Comment: Thanks @BrunoVolpato. It turns out our composer is of old version and in-turn that composer version uses java 8 as runtime version.
With composer version - composer-1.17.0, runtime got updated to java 11.
"Java Runtime in Airflow workers and schedulers is updated from version 8 to version 11."
Didn't realize it is not a configurable value unlike Python version :)